# Apagar registro com (Id) duplicado deixando somente uma ocorrência

Tags: sql, sql-server, normalização

Trata-se de um banco antigo, `dbase` que foi transferido para `MSSQL`. 
Como deixar somente uma ocorrência no caso de `id` duplicado em uma tabela?

```
| Id| Nome  |
|-----------|
| 1 | JOSE  |
| 1 | JOSE  |
| 2 | MARIA |
| 2 | MARIA |
| 2 | MARIA |
```

Comment: Você quer deletar todos os registros duplicados deixando apenas um?

Comment: Isso, um de cada.

Comment: Faz um select distinct em todos os campos. Insere o resultado deste select em uma outra tabela (auxiliar), apaga os dados da tabela original e insere os dados da tabela auxiliar na original. Isso deve resolver.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar tabelas temporárias para lhe auxiliar:

```
select distinct * into #tmp From tabela
delete from tabela
insert into tabela
select * from #tmp drop table #tmp
```

Comment: Eu só usaria uma tabela concreta, ao invés de uma tabela temporária. Precaução nunca é demais. :) Ou então, se fosse usar uma temporária, usaria a que vale pra qualquer sessão: ##tmp

Comment: ai depende da situação do colega que questionou, eu particularmente usaria temporária. mas concordo com sua colocação, precaução nunca é demais.

Comment: isso  não daria muito certo se tivesse dependência entre outras tabelas ....

Comment: ele não mencionou dependências com outras tabelas, presumo que os relacionamentos de vendas sejam apenas estas tabelas mencionadas.

Comment: Concordo com o @Hoppy. Veja o enunciado: "Como deixar somente uma ocorrência no caso de id duplicado em uma tabela?" O autor cita "uma tabela".

Comment: @cantoni, o autor não mencionou, mas e quanto os outro que precisarem de uma resposta parecida? só falei que se tive relacionamento isso não dar certo... o mais correto num caso deste tipo seria um loop e verificar se existe apenas um registro distinto...

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza o autor não mencionou se o serviço do MSSQL está rodando, se ele mencionasse na pergunta eu indicaria para ele ligar, assim como interpretei a questão imposta, o usuário possúi apenas uma tabela e sem relacionamento. Não há forma de fazer uma limpeza genérica que funciona para todos os tipos de relacionamentos. Cada caso pode ser um caso.

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza, é complicado montar uma resposta que sirva pra todo mundo. Até porque a pergunta teria que ser outra. Eu mesmo quando preciso buscar um assunto, costumo achar várias repostas no SO, quando não encontro tudo numa questão só, faço um merge das soluções.

Comment: @cantoni, a ultima explicação eu até aceito ... ta menos rude. vale até um voto ...

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza peço desculpas se me interpretou errado, não foi intencional ser rude.

Answer (score 1):

VC pode esta fazendo um cursor da seguinte forma..

```
 insert into tabela values
 (1 , 'JOSE'),
 (1 , 'JOSE' ),
 (2 , 'MARIA' ),
 (2 , 'MARIA' ),
 (1 , 'JOSE'),
 (1 , 'JOSE' ),
 (2 , 'MARIA' ),
 (2 , 'MARIA' ),
 (1 , 'JOSE'),
 (1 , 'JOSE' ),
 (2 , 'MARIA' ),
 (3 , 'antonio' ),
 (3 , 'antonio' ),
 (3 , 'antonio' ),
 (3 , 'antonio' ),
 (3 , 'antonio' ),
 (3 , 'antonio' ),
 (2 , 'MARIA' )

DECLARE @name VARCHAR(100) 
DECLARE @id int 

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
select * from tabela  

OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @id , @name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
      if( select count(id) from tabela t where id= @id group by Nome having count(id) = 1) = 1
       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO  @id , @name   
       else
       begin 
           delete top(1) t
             from tabela t
             join (
                 select  count(id) as id, Nome from tabela t
                 group by Nome
                 having count(id) > 1
             )d
             on d.Nome = t.Nome
        end
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
select * from tabela ;
```

[image]